# Can I convert a C# string value to an escaped string literal?

Tags: c#, string, escaping

In C#, can I convert a string value to a string literal, the way I would see it in code? I would like to replace tabs, newlines, etc. with their escape sequences.

If this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(someString);
```

produces:

```
Hello
World!
```

I want this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(ToLiteral(someString));
```

to produce:

```
\tHello\r\n\tWorld!\r\n
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There's a method for this in [Roslyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compiler_Platform)'s [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/) package on NuGet:

```cs
private static string ToLiteral(string valueTextForCompiler)
{
    return Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplay.FormatLiteral(valueTextForCompiler, false);
}
```

Obviously, this didn't exist at the time of the original question, but it might help people who end up here from Google Search.

Comment: this is a nice way to do it from .net core.

Comment: Yes, the package supports .NET Core and .NET Standard 2.0 - meaning it can also be referenced from .NET Framework 4.6.1+

Comment: Also useful in source generators.

Comment: This is the only way that escaped all the characters for me

Comment: Works great, but I need a way to restore the original unescaped string.

Comment: If you want escaping of double quotes within the value, you need to use `SymbolDisplay.FormatLiteral( valueTextForCompiler, true )[ 1..^1 ]`. The range expression at the end strips off the surrounding double quotes that get added when you pass `true`.

Answer (score 208):

A long time ago, I found this:

```
private static string ToLiteral(string input)
{
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
        {
            provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(input), writer, null);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This code:

```
var input = "\tHello\r\n\tWorld!";
Console.WriteLine(input);
Console.WriteLine(ToLiteral(input));
```

Produces:

```
    Hello
    World!
"\tHello\r\n\tWorld!"
```

These days, [Graham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1128762/graham) discovered you can use Roslyn's Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp package on NuGet:

```
private static string ToLiteral(string valueTextForCompiler)
{
    return Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplay.FormatLiteral(valueTextForCompiler, false);
}
```

Comment: Just found this from google the subject. This has to be best, no point in reinventing stuff that .net can do for us

Comment: Nice one, but be aware that for longer strings, this will insert "+" operators, newlines and indentation. I couldn't find a way to turn that off.

Comment: Oh, also — the ".GetStringBuilder()" is redundant. You can just use .ToString() directly on a StringWriter.

Comment: This doesn't even take care \f.

Comment: What about the inverse ? If you have a file with text containg escape sequences incluidng especial character escaped with its ascii code ? How to produce a raw version ?

Comment: If you run: void Main()
{
  Console.WriteLine(ToLiteral("test \"\'\\\0\a\b\f\n\r\t\v\uaaaa \\\blah"));
} you'll notice that this doesn't take care of a few escapes. Ronnie Overby pointed \f, the others are \a and \b

Comment: My weekend project: An implementation of this routine on a mvc form. If you only need to do this occasionally, you can hit my page at http://csharpstringescape.apphb.com/ (code is on github)

Comment: Is there a way to make it output verbatim (`@"..."`) literals?

Comment: @rookie1024 I'm interested as well. Using this gives me mixed results, some are `@\"..\"` some are just `\"...\"`

Comment: I put an answer at the bottom to attempt to add a verbatim version of Hallgrim's answer.  I'm guessing it isn't perfect, I'll use it for awhile and see how it works.

Comment: Don't forget `using System.CodeDom;` and `using System.CodeDom.Compiler;` at the top of the code!

Comment: Didn't for everything for me including `\a` and `\u0004`. [Graham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58825732) is the only one which worked properly for me

Comment: Don't know what this is, but it does not work.

Answer (score 52):

Use [Regex.Escape(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx):

> Regex.Escape escapes a minimal set of characters (, *, +, ?, |, {, [,
> (,), ^, $,., #, and white space) by replacing them with their escape
> codes.

Comment: +1 no idea why this is way below. Other answers are just too verbose and look like reinventing wheels

Comment: This is not what OP is asking for. It doesn't return a string literal, it returns a string with Regex special characters escaped. This would turn `Hello World?` into `Hello World\?`, but that is an invalid string literal.

Comment: I agree with @atheaos, this is a great answer to a very different question.

Comment: +1 even though it doesn't quite answer the OP's question it was what I (and so I suspect maybe others) were looking for when I came across this question. :)

Comment: This will not work as needed. The regex special characters are not the same. It will work for \n for example, but when you have a space, it will be converted to "\ " which is not what C# would do...

Answer (score 32):

This is a fully working implementation, including escaping of Unicode and ASCII non-printable characters. It does not insert "+" signs like [Hallgrim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/324812/254101).

```
static string ToLiteral(string input) {
    StringBuilder literal = new StringBuilder(input.Length + 2);
    literal.Append("\"");
    foreach (var c in input) {
        switch (c) {
            case '\"': literal.Append("\\\""); break;
            case '\\': literal.Append(@"\\"); break;
            case '\0': literal.Append(@"\0"); break;
            case '\a': literal.Append(@"\a"); break;
            case '\b': literal.Append(@"\b"); break;
            case '\f': literal.Append(@"\f"); break;
            case '\n': literal.Append(@"\n"); break;
            case '\r': literal.Append(@"\r"); break;
            case '\t': literal.Append(@"\t"); break;
            case '\v': literal.Append(@"\v"); break;
            default:
                // ASCII printable character
                if (c >= 0x20 && c <= 0x7e) {
                    literal.Append(c);
                // As UTF16 escaped character
                } else {
                    literal.Append(@"\u");
                    literal.Append(((int)c).ToString("x4"));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    literal.Append("\"");
    return literal.ToString();
}
```

Note that this also escapes all Unicode characters. If your environment supports them, you could change that part to escape only control characters:

```
// UTF16 control characters
} else if (Char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.Control) {
    literal.Append(@"\u");
    literal.Append(((int)c).ToString("x4"));
} else {
    literal.Append(c);
}
```

Comment: You should use `Char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.Control` to decide whether to escape it, or people who don't speak ASCII won't be very happy.

Comment: This depends on situation if your resulting string will be used in the environment supporting unicode or not.

Comment: I added `input = input ?? string.Empty;` as the first line of the method so I could pass `null` and get back `""` instead of a null reference exception.

Comment: Nice. Change enclosing quotes to `'` and now you have what Python gives you out of the box with `repr(a_string)` :).

Comment: Why did you escape `'` as that is not necessary?

Comment: @trinalbadger587 I don't remember, it was 10 years ago. :) But you're right, escaping `'` is most likely unnecessary.

Comment: @Smilediver, you should edit your answer then.

Answer (score 26):

A more structured approach, including all escape sequences for `string`s and `char`s, is:

It doesn't replace Unicode characters with their literal equivalent. It doesn't cook eggs, either.

```
public class ReplaceString
{
    static readonly IDictionary<string, string> m_replaceDict
        = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    const string ms_regexEscapes = @"[\a\b\f\n\r\t\v\\""]";

    public static string StringLiteral(string i_string)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(i_string, ms_regexEscapes, match);
    }

    public static string CharLiteral(char c)
    {
        return c == '\'' ? @"'\''" : string.Format("'{0}'", c);
    }

    private static string match(Match m)
    {
        string match = m.ToString();
        if (m_replaceDict.ContainsKey(match))
        {
            return m_replaceDict[match];
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    static ReplaceString()
    {
        m_replaceDict.Add("\a", @"\a");
        m_replaceDict.Add("\b", @"\b");
        m_replaceDict.Add("\f", @"\f");
        m_replaceDict.Add("\n", @"\n");
        m_replaceDict.Add("\r", @"\r");
        m_replaceDict.Add("\t", @"\t");
        m_replaceDict.Add("\v", @"\v");

        m_replaceDict.Add("\\", @"\\");
        m_replaceDict.Add("\0", @"\0");

        //The SO parser gets fooled by the verbatim version
        //of the string to replace - @"\"""
        //so use the 'regular' version
        m_replaceDict.Add("\"", "\\\"");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args){

        string s = "here's a \"\n\tstring\" to test";
        Console.WriteLine(ReplaceString.StringLiteral(s));
        Console.WriteLine(ReplaceString.CharLiteral('c'));
        Console.WriteLine(ReplaceString.CharLiteral('\''));

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not all escape sequences ;)

Comment: Works better than the solution above - and other escape sequences can easily be added.

Comment: Verbatim in the accepted answer was driving me bonkers. This works 100% for my purpose. Replaced regex with `@"[\a\b\f\n\r\t\v\\""/]"`and added `m_replaceDict.Add("/", @"\/");` for `JSON`.

Comment: Also, you have to add the enclosing quotations to this if you want those.

Answer (score 21):

Try:

```
var t = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(s);
```

Comment: Does not work. If I have "abc\n123" (without quotes, 8 chars), I want "abc" + \n + "123" (7 chars).  Instead it produces "abc" + "\\" + "\n123" (9 chars).  Notice the slash was doubled and it still contains a string literal of "\n" as two characters, not the escaped character.

Comment: @Paul What you want is the opposite of what the question is asking, though. This, according to your description, answers the question, and therefore _does_ work.

Comment: I found this useful to escape active directory names in the frontend

Answer (score 19):

```
public static class StringHelpers
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> escapeMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"\"", @"\\\"""},
        {"\\\\", @"\\"},
        {"\a", @"\a"},
        {"\b", @"\b"},
        {"\f", @"\f"},
        {"\n", @"\n"},
        {"\r", @"\r"},
        {"\t", @"\t"},
        {"\v", @"\v"},
        {"\0", @"\0"},
    };

    private static Regex escapeRegex = new Regex(string.Join("|", escapeMapping.Keys.ToArray()));

    public static string Escape(this string s)
    {
        return escapeRegex.Replace(s, EscapeMatchEval);
    }

    private static string EscapeMatchEval(Match m)
    {
        if (escapeMapping.ContainsKey(m.Value))
        {
            return escapeMapping[m.Value];
        }
        return escapeMapping[Regex.Escape(m.Value)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is there 3 backslashes and two speech marks in the first value of the dictionary?

Comment: Nice answer, @JamesYeoman that's because regex pattern needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 19):

[Hallgrim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/324812/254101) is excellent, but the "+", newline and indent additions were breaking functionality for me.  An easy way around it is:

```
private static string ToLiteral(string input)
{
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
        {
            provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(input), writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions {IndentString = "\t"});
            var literal = writer.ToString();
            literal = literal.Replace(string.Format("\" +{0}\t\"", Environment.NewLine), "");
            return literal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great. I also added one line before the `return literal` to make it more readable:  
`literal = literal.Replace("\\r\\n", "\\r\\n\"+\r\n\"");`

Comment: Added this `literal = literal.Replace("/", @"\/");` for `JSON` functionality.

Comment: This is 100% straight forward and the only correct answer! All other answers either didn't understand the question or re-invented the wheel.

Comment: Sad, cannot get this to work under DOTNET CORE. Anyone has a better answer?

Answer (score 10):

Here is a little improvement for [Smilediver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal/14087738#14087738). It will not escape all no-ASCII characters, but only these are really needed.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

public static class CodeHelper
{
    public static string ToLiteral(this string input)
    {
        var literal = new StringBuilder(input.Length + 2);
        literal.Append("\"");
        foreach (var c in input)
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case '\'': literal.Append(@"\'"); break;
                case '\"': literal.Append("\\\""); break;
                case '\\': literal.Append(@"\\"); break;
                case '\0': literal.Append(@"\0"); break;
                case '\a': literal.Append(@"\a"); break;
                case '\b': literal.Append(@"\b"); break;
                case '\f': literal.Append(@"\f"); break;
                case '\n': literal.Append(@"\n"); break;
                case '\r': literal.Append(@"\r"); break;
                case '\t': literal.Append(@"\t"); break;
                case '\v': literal.Append(@"\v"); break;
                default:
                    if (Char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.Control)
                    {
                        literal.Append(c);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        literal.Append(@"\u");
                        literal.Append(((ushort)c).ToString("x4"));
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        literal.Append("\"");
        return literal.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Interesting question.

If you can't find a better method, you can always replace.
In case you're opting for it, you could use this **C# Escape Sequence List**:

- \' - single quote, needed for character literals
- \" - double quote, needed for string literals
- \ - backslash
- \0 - Unicode character 0
- \a - Alert (character 7)
- \b - Backspace (character 8)
- \f - Form feed (character 12)
- \n - New line (character 10)
- \r - Carriage return (character 13)
- \t - Horizontal tab (character 9)
- \v - Vertical quote (character 11)
- \uxxxx - Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value xxxx
- \xn[n][n][n] - Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value nnnn (variable length version of \uxxxx)
- \Uxxxxxxxx - Unicode escape sequence for character with hex value xxxxxxxx (for generating surrogates)

This list can be found in the C# Frequently Asked Questions
[What character escape sequences are available?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/)

Comment: This link no longer works, a textbook example of why link-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Very true, @James, but thanks to Jamie Twells the information is available again :+1:

Answer (score 4):

If JSON conventions are enough for the unescaped strings you want to get escaped and you already use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) (`Newtonsoft.Json`) in your project (it has a pretty large overhead), you may use this package like the following:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ToLiteral(@"abc\n123"));
    }

    private static string ToLiteral(string input)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>("\"" + input + "\"");
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the opposite of what OP wants? `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input).Trim('"')` works great though.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class StringEscape
{
  static char[] toEscape = "\0\x1\x2\x3\x4\x5\x6\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\xe\xf\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\"\\".ToCharArray();
  static string[] literals = @"\0,\x0001,\x0002,\x0003,\x0004,\x0005,\x0006,\a,\b,\t,\n,\v,\f,\r,\x000e,\x000f,\x0010,\x0011,\x0012,\x0013,\x0014,\x0015,\x0016,\x0017,\x0018,\x0019,\x001a,\x001b,\x001c,\x001d,\x001e,\x001f".Split(new char[] { ',' });

  public static string Escape(this string input)
  {
    int i = input.IndexOfAny(toEscape);
    if (i < 0) return input;

    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(input.Length + 5);
    int j = 0;
    do
    {
      sb.Append(input, j, i - j);
      var c = input[i];
      if (c < 0x20) sb.Append(literals[c]); else sb.Append(@"\").Append(c);
    } while ((i = input.IndexOfAny(toEscape, j = ++i)) > 0);

    return sb.Append(input, j, input.Length - j).ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? E.g., is it due to performance considerations? Please respond by editing your answer, not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

My attempt at adding *ToVerbatim* to [Hallgrim's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/324812/254101):

```
private static string ToLiteral(string input)
{
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
        {
            provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(input), writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions { IndentString = "\t" });
            var literal = writer.ToString();
            literal = literal.Replace(string.Format("\" +{0}\t\"", Environment.NewLine), "");
            return literal;
        }
    }
}

private static string ToVerbatim(string input)
{
    string literal = ToLiteral(input);
    string verbatim = "@" + literal.Replace(@"\r\n", Environment.NewLine);
    return verbatim;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Hallgrim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal/324812#324812) was excellent. Here's a small tweak in case you need to parse out additional white space characters and linebreaks with a C# regular expression. I needed this in the case of a serialized JSON value for insertion into [Google Sheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Sheets) and ran into trouble as the code was inserting tabs, +, spaces, etc.

```
  provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(input), writer, null);
  var literal = writer.ToString();
  var r2 = new Regex(@"\"" \+.\n[\s]+\""", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
  literal = r2.Replace(literal, "");
  return literal;
```

Answer (score -1):

I submit my own implementation, which handles `null` values and should be more performant on account of using array lookup tables, manual hex conversion, and avoiding `switch` statements.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;

public static class StringLiteralEncoding {
  private static readonly char[] HEX_DIGIT_LOWER = "0123456789abcdef".ToCharArray();
  private static readonly char[] LITERALENCODE_ESCAPE_CHARS;

  static StringLiteralEncoding() {
    // Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx
    var escapes = new string[] { "\aa", "\bb", "\ff", "\nn", "\rr", "\tt", "\vv", "\"\"", "\\\\", "??", "\00" };
    LITERALENCODE_ESCAPE_CHARS = new char[escapes.Max(e => e[0]) + 1];
    foreach(var escape in escapes)
      LITERALENCODE_ESCAPE_CHARS[escape[0]] = escape[1];
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Convert the string to the equivalent C# string literal, enclosing the string in double quotes and inserting
  /// escape sequences as necessary.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="s">The string to be converted to a C# string literal.</param>
  /// <returns><paramref name="s"/> represented as a C# string literal.</returns>
  public static string Encode(string s) {
    if(null == s) return "null";

    var sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length + 2).Append('"');
    for(var rp = 0; rp < s.Length; rp++) {
      var c = s[rp];
      if(c < LITERALENCODE_ESCAPE_CHARS.Length && '\0' != LITERALENCODE_ESCAPE_CHARS[c])
        sb.Append('\\').Append(LITERALENCODE_ESCAPE_CHARS[c]);
      else if('~' >= c && c >= ' ')
        sb.Append(c);
      else
        sb.Append(@"\x")
          .Append(HEX_DIGIT_LOWER[c >> 12 & 0x0F])
          .Append(HEX_DIGIT_LOWER[c >>  8 & 0x0F])
          .Append(HEX_DIGIT_LOWER[c >>  4 & 0x0F])
          .Append(HEX_DIGIT_LOWER[c       & 0x0F]);
    }

    return sb.Append('"').ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are `switch` statements bad? Aren't they optimised by the compiler (lookup tables or similar)?

Answer (score -10):

**Code:**

```
string someString1 = "\tHello\r\n\tWorld!\r\n";
string someString2 = @"\tHello\r\n\tWorld!\r\n";

Console.WriteLine(someString1);
Console.WriteLine(someString2);
```

**Output:**

```
    Hello
    World!

\tHello\r\n\tWorld!\r\n
```

Comment: I have someString1, but it is read from a file. I want it to appear as someString2 after calling some method.

Comment: The string may be dynamically created/obtained he needs a method to handle any string