# Verbatim strings and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to get Visual Studio to display strings as verbatim strings (prefixed with '@')? I'd like to easily cut strings containing file paths from Visual Studio into Explorer or other apps.

Clarification: when VS displays a string in the auto, watch, immediate, etc. window, I'd like it to be formatted as as verbatim string so that I can simple copy it for use elsewhere.

Comment: Where are you wanting to display these? In the debugger?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759324/can-the-visual-studio-debugger-display-strings-unquoted-unescaped

Answer (score 7):

You can click on the magnifier in VS 2008 debugger variable display and select "Text Visualizer" which will give you the text in an unmassaged format.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clarify your question.  My first thought was that you just need to prefix the string with '@' to make them verbatim, but you already know that.

```
string s = @"c:\my folder\";
```

What exactly are you trying to do with the string?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a discussion on how to actually build verbatim-ized strings: 
[Can I convert a C# string value to a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-string-value-to-a-string-literal#323670).

Plugging this in a debug vizualiser is a different story...