# Can the Visual Studio Debugger display strings unquoted/unescaped?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, debuggervisualizer

The managed debugger in Visual Studio (I am using 11.0) displays string values containing double quotes and backslashes like this:

```
"{\"Text\":\"C:\\\\Temp\"}"
```

Occasionally I would like to display an escaped text like the above one in its plain form:

```
{"Text":"C:\\Temp"}
```

I am aware of the text visualizer which is accessible via the magnifying glass next to the value, but this is rather cumbersome during debugging some text manipulation routine.

Is there a way to change the display of string values in the debugger?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I see two options that may be less cumbersome then clicking the magnifying glass each time, depending on the situation:

1. Right click the value and hit 'Add To Watch', then edit the expression that was added to watch and add `,nq` (the 'no quotes' [format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e514eeby%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)) at the end. For example, "myJsonObject.JsonText,nq". From then on, look at the Watch window (rather than the data-tip) to see the values as you step through your code.
2. Using [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com/), right click the expression and select [Add Custom Expressions](http://www.oz-code.com/features#custom), and add a custom expression with `,nq` at the end. For example: `[obj].JsonText,nq`.

**Full disclosure:** OzCode is a commercial VS extension that I am co-author of, currently free while in beta.

Answer (score 10):

I just found one more way of doing this in the debugger window.

Instead of

```
?myStringVariable
```

use

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.print(myStringVariable, {"nq"})
```

That seems to stop the double quoting.

EDIT: An even easier way:

```
?myStringVariable,nq
```

Thats working for me in Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Shame it doesn't work in javascript. Since discovering this I've added several dump functions to my code such as "DumpDataTable" which I can call with ?DumpDataTable(myDataTable),nq  ... that gives a really cool and fast way of quickly seeing object contents in the debug window