# Getting error "System.InvalidOperationException. There is an error in XML document (1, 2)." during Deserialization in C#

Tags: c#, restsharp

Trying to Deserialise XML response to C#. but getting error as specified below.

My code:

```
IRestResponse result = Client.Execute<StudentPersonal>(new RestRequest(Method.POST)
    .AddHeader("Accept", " application/xml")
    .AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic Y2xaTWNqZFFlbFF4YVU1TlFtUnZOV3hXTkhadmNHaFhPSGxTT0Rka1VIcFhhRTl5TWtWQ05rRjNUMlp5VlUxWlNYa3hjbEU1V1RGUmMxTkNOMlZWVlRvNk9nPT06eUkxdERIanNVcGxLUUpzUlNXNTVacXpRVUFGQ3JrZzFwUGxUbDhUTmRQaFU0Z0xsTFJlQkVxTmhzZml3TnpaVA==")
    .AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml")
    .AddParameter("application/xml", body, ParameterType.RequestBody));

StudentPersonal firstResponse = new StudentPersonal();
StringReader srt = new StringReader(result.Content);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StudentPersonal), new XmlRootAttribute("StudentPersonal"));
firstResponse = (StudentPersonal)serializer.Deserialize(srt);
Console.WriteLine(firstResponse);
Assert.AreEqual("Created", result.StatusCode.ToString());
```

My classes:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "StudentPersonal")]
public class StudentPersonal
{
    //// XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StudentPersonal));
    //// using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    //// {
    ////    var test = (StudentPersonal)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    //// }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LocalId")]
    public double LocalId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "StateProvinceId")]
    public int StateProvinceId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ElectronicIdList")]
    public object ElectronicIdList { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "OtherIdList")]
    public OtherIdList OtherIdList { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PersonInfo")]
    public PersonInfo PersonInfo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GiftedTalented")]
    public string GiftedTalented { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "EconomicDisadvantage")]
    public string EconomicDisadvantage { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ESL")]
    public string ESL { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "YoungCarersRole")]
    public string YoungCarersRole { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Disability")]
    public string Disability { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "IntegrationAide")]
    public string IntegrationAide { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "EducationSupport")]
    public string EducationSupport { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sensitive")]
    public string Sensitive { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd")]
    public string Xsd { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi")]
    public string Xsi { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "RefId")]
    public string RefId { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "OtherId")]
public class OtherId
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public int Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "OtherIdList")]
public class OtherIdList
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "OtherId")]
    public List<OtherId> OtherId { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Name")]
public class Name
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FamilyName")]
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GivenName")]
    public string GivenName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MiddleName")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FamilyNameFirst")]
    public string FamilyNameFirst { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PreferredFamilyName")]
    public string PreferredFamilyName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PreferredFamilyNameFirst")]
    public string PreferredFamilyNameFirst { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PreferredGivenName")]
    public string PreferredGivenName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FullName")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "EnglishProficiency")]
public class EnglishProficiency
{

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Language")]
public class Language
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LanguageType")]
    public int LanguageType { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "LanguageList")]
public class LanguageList
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Language")]
    public List<Language> Language { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DwellingArrangement")]
public class DwellingArrangement
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Religion")]
public class Religion
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Code")]
    public int Code { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ReligiousEvent")]
public class ReligiousEvent
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ReligiousEventList")]
public class ReligiousEventList
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReligiousEvent")]
    public ReligiousEvent ReligiousEvent { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Demographics")]
public class Demographics
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "IndigenousStatus")]
    public int IndigenousStatus { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sex")]
    public int Sex { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "BirthDate")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "BirthDateVerification")]
    public int BirthDateVerification { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CountryArrivalDate")]
    public DateTime CountryArrivalDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "EnglishProficiency")]
    public EnglishProficiency EnglishProficiency { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LanguageList")]
    public LanguageList LanguageList { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DwellingArrangement")]
    public DwellingArrangement DwellingArrangement { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Religion")]
    public Religion Religion { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReligiousEventList")]
    public ReligiousEventList ReligiousEventList { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PermanentResident")]
    public string PermanentResident { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "VisaSubClass")]
    public int VisaSubClass { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "VisaStatisticalCode")]
    public string VisaStatisticalCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "VisaExpiryDate")]
    public DateTime VisaExpiryDate { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LBOTE")]
    public string LBOTE { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ImmunisationCertificateStatus")]
    public string ImmunisationCertificateStatus { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CulturalBackground")]
    public int CulturalBackground { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MaritalStatus")]
    public int MaritalStatus { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MedicareNumber")]
    public int MedicareNumber { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PhoneNumber")]
public class PhoneNumber
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ListedStatus")]
    public string ListedStatus { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Type")]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PhoneNumberList")]
public class PhoneNumberList
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PhoneNumber")]
    public PhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Email")]
public class Email
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Type")]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "EmailList")]
public class EmailList
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Email")]
    public List<Email> Email { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PersonInfo")]
public class PersonInfo
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public Name Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Demographics")]
    public Demographics Demographics { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AddressList")]
    public object AddressList { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PhoneNumberList")]
    public PhoneNumberList PhoneNumberList { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "EmailList")]
    public EmailList EmailList { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the response XML details from `Result.content`:

```xml
<StudentPersonal xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" RefId=\"9ec476fd-09b5-4b2b-967a-fb80b207526e\" xmlns=\"http://www.sifassociation.org/datamodel/au/3.4\">
    <LocalId>2432717276450097998</LocalId>
    <StateProvinceId>674361</StateProvinceId>
    <ElectronicIdList />
    <OtherIdList>
        <OtherId Type=\"MazeKey\">674363</OtherId>
        <OtherId Type=\"VETUSI\">674362</OtherId>
        <OtherId Type=\"UPN\">674363</OtherId>
    </OtherIdList>
    <PersonInfo>
        <Name Type=\"LGL\">
            <Title>Ms</Title>
            <FamilyName>Gutteridge2</FamilyName>
            <GivenName>Ferdinanda2</GivenName>
            <MiddleName>Creamer1</MiddleName>
            <FamilyNameFirst>N</FamilyNameFirst>
            <PreferredFamilyName>Gutteridge</PreferredFamilyName>
            <PreferredFamilyNameFirst>N</PreferredFamilyNameFirst>
            <PreferredGivenName>Ferdinanda</PreferredGivenName>
            <FullName> Ferdinanda Gutteridge</FullName>
        </Name>
        <Demographics>
            <IndigenousStatus>1</IndigenousStatus>
            <Sex>2</Sex>
            <BirthDate>2006-03-21</BirthDate>
            <BirthDateVerification>1004</BirthDateVerification>
            <CountryArrivalDate>2008-09-17</CountryArrivalDate>
            <EnglishProficiency>
                <Code>1</Code>
            </EnglishProficiency>
            <LanguageList>
                <Language>
                    <Code>1201</Code>
                    <LanguageType>3</LanguageType>
                </Language>
                <Language>
                    <Code>4303</Code>
                    <LanguageType>1</LanguageType>
                </Language>
                <Language>
                    <Code>4303</Code>
                    <LanguageType>1</LanguageType>
                </Language>
            </LanguageList>
            <DwellingArrangement>
                <Code>1671</Code>
            </DwellingArrangement>
            <Religion>
                <Code>0002</Code>
            </Religion>
            <ReligiousEventList>
                <ReligiousEvent>
                    <Type>Confirmation</Type>
                    <Date>2018-07-17</Date>
                </ReligiousEvent>
            </ReligiousEventList>
            <PermanentResident>P</PermanentResident>
            <VisaSubClass>124</VisaSubClass>
            <VisaStatisticalCode>VisaStatisticalCode</VisaStatisticalCode>
            <VisaExpiryDate>2019-01-17</VisaExpiryDate>
            <LBOTE>N</LBOTE>
            <ImmunisationCertificateStatus>C</ImmunisationCertificateStatus>
            <CulturalBackground>0901</CulturalBackground>
            <MaritalStatus>3</MaritalStatus>
            <MedicareNumber>67436</MedicareNumber>
        </Demographics>
        <AddressList />
        <PhoneNumberList>
            <PhoneNumber Type=\"0350\">
                <Number>12367436</Number>
                <ListedStatus>U</ListedStatus>
            </PhoneNumber>
        </PhoneNumberList>
        <EmailList>
            <Email Type=\"01\">person67436@email1.com.au</Email>
            <Email Type=\"02\">person67436@email2.com.au</Email>
            <Email Type=\"03\">person67436@email3.com.au</Email>
        </EmailList>
    </PersonInfo>
    <GiftedTalented>N</GiftedTalented>
    <EconomicDisadvantage>N</EconomicDisadvantage>
    <ESL>N</ESL>
    <YoungCarersRole>N</YoungCarersRole>
    <Disability>N</Disability>
    <IntegrationAide>N</IntegrationAide>
    <EducationSupport>U</EducationSupport>
    <Sensitive>N</Sensitive>
</StudentPersonal>
```

Error is from the above XML response.  Getting Error

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 2). InvalidOperationException: <StudentPersonal xmlns='http://www.sifassociation.org/datamodel/au/3.4'> was not expected.
```

Comment: you should provide what `resul.Content` evaluates to when you execute that code. It's impossible for us to guess why an xml may be invalid if you don't provide that xml.

Comment: If the XML has a namespace, you have to add it to the XmlRoot attribute, too: `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "StudentPersonal", Namespace = "http://www.sifassociation.org/datamodel/au/3.4")]`

Comment: Looks like your `StudentPersonal` class doesn't specify that XML namespace? E.g. `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "StudentPersonal", Namespace = "http://www.sifassociation.org/datamodel/au/3.4")]`

Comment: Hmm - how do double quotes turn into single quotes here?

Comment: Added ```result.Content``` details

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two issues.

1. Add the namespace to your class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "StudentPersonal", Namespace = "http://www.sifassociation.org/datamodel/au/3.4")]
public class StudentPersonal
          ...
```

2. In the XML, all `"` are escaped with `\`.

```
<StudentPersonal xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" RefId=\"9ec476fd-09b5-4b2b-967a-fb80b207526e\" xmlns=\"http://www.sifassociation.org/datamodel/au/3.4\">
                ...
</StudentPersonal>
```

This also occurs in other places throughout the XML. Such as:

`<PhoneNumber Type=\"0350\">`

To resolve the issue, replace all occurrences of `\"` with `"`.

```
<StudentPersonal xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" RefId="9ec476fd-09b5-4b2b-967a-fb80b207526e" xmlns="http://www.sifassociation.org/datamodel/au/3.4">
                ...
</StudentPersonal>
```

and

`<PhoneNumber Type="0350">`

Here's a method that can be used to deserialize the XML:

**DeserializeXMLStringToObject**:

```
public static T DeserializeXMLStringToObject<T>(string xmlData)
{
    T rObject = default(T);

    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlData))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        //replace \" with "
        string xmlDataSanitized = xmlData.Replace("\\\"", "\"");

        using (System.IO.StringReader reader = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlDataSanitized))
        {
            //add the namespace to the class instead of adding it here
            //System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T), "http://www.sifassociation.org/datamodel/au/3.4");
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            rObject = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }

    return rObject;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
private StudentPersonal _studentPersonal = null;
                ...

_studentPersonal = DeserializeXMLStringToObject<StudentPersonal>(result.Content);

//for testing, display some of the data
//System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LocalId: " + _studentPersonal.LocalId);
//System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GivenName: " + _studentPersonal.PersonInfo.Name.GivenName);
```

Comment: even if I convert ```\"``` to ```"``` , the ```StringReader``` object will again add ```\"``` in the code.

Comment: @TusharPrajapati: I've updated the post.

Comment: Regarding the string escaping, I think that @TusharPrajapati was confused by Visual Studio that adds c# string escaping around strings when displaying them.  To see the raw string without any "helpful" VS escaping, see [Stop visual studio debug putting slash in string containing double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41172620/3744182) and [Can the Visual Studio Debugger display strings unquoted/unescaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18759324/3744182).

Comment: You are correct. Visual studio Text Visualizer displays  XML without ```\"``` while debugging. I just remove xmlns attributes and NameSpaces with below code and It is working fine. ```var test1 = Regex.Replace(result.Content, "((?<=<|<\\/)|(?<= ))[A-Za-z0-9]+:| xmlns(:[A-Za-z0-9]+)?=\".*?\"", "");```