# Decoding TextBox.Text from a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a GridView control. Each row has a textbox with a description I need. When I pull back the description I see that the (") has been encoded:

```
TextBox selectedRowTextbox = (TextBox)selectedRow.Cells[5].Controls[1];
string selectedRowText = selectedRowTextbox.Text;
```

The result:

```
24\" Sparkle Disco Ball
```

I have tried:

- Server.HtmlDecode
- Regex.Unescape
- Uri.UnescapeDataString
- Regex.Replace

What I would expect is this:

```
24" Sparkle Disco Ball
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` method to decode the text.

```
TextBox selectedRowTextbox = (TextBox)selectedRow.Cells[5].Controls[1];
string selectedRowText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(selectedRowTextbox.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. Visual Studio displays string values containing double quotes and backslashes like this in my example. That's not a great thing to do IMHO.

Here's a link to read me about it.
[Can the Visual Studio Debugger display strings unquoted/unescaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759324/can-the-visual-studio-debugger-display-strings-unquoted-unescaped)

Comment: Well, it can be debated, but "once" you a developer learns the above, then everyone else is VERY happy to see the escaped characters in the string --- it is VERY useful!