# Built in method to get C-style escaped sequence for a string

Tags: c#, .net, escaping

Is there a built method in .Net for C-style escaping of strings?

For example, I have to convert a string which **contains quotes** like `"hello"`, and write it as an escaped string `\"hello\"`.

Actually, to be more precise:

```
string original = "\"hello\"";
```

should be converted to

```
string what_i_need = "\\\"hello\\\"";
```

I could have probably done it myself while writing this question, but I don't want to reinvent hot water.

**[Edit]** According to the provided answer, this is actually a **duplicate of**: [Can I convert a C# string value to a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-string-value-to-a-string-literal). It didn't pop out since there were no tags and keywords I was looking for.

Comment: And how will you provide the string to that function? "\"hello\"" without escape sequence is invalid string.

Comment: Why invalid? It's a string which contains quotes, and I need to escape those quotes (and/or other "special" characters) before writing the string to a text file. Otherwise a third party app is unable to read the file - it considers a quote to be the end of the string and fails.

Comment: I mean "\"hello"\" without \ is not a string even if you use @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is any built in methods. But if you have to write your own, [Can I convert a C# string value to a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-string-value-to-a-string-literal) post maybe helpful

Comment: +1, thanks, I will check the code provided by Cristi Diaconescu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-string-value-to-a-string-literal/323670#323670.