# converting string to string literal

Tags: java, string, string-literals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you convert a String to a Java string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453231/how-would-you-convert-a-string-to-a-java-string-literal)

Is there a library function that takes a string and converts is into a corresponding string literal? Example:

`Please say\ask "What?" three times!` -> `"Please say\\ask \"What?\" three times!"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think commons lang StringUtils does that

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html