# Convert an escaped string to an String Array

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

I have this kind of String

```
string input="[\"Modell\",\"Jan.\",\"Feb.\",\"Mrz.\",\"Apr.\",\"Mai\",\"Jun.\",\"Jul.\",\"Aug.\",\"Sep.\",\"Okt.\",\"Nov.\",\"Dez.\"]";
```

I need to convert it into something like this:

```
string[] output;//convert "input" to it
```

I was looking at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889057/c-sharp-how-can-i-convert-an-escaped-string-into-a-literal-string),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889057/c-sharp-how-can-i-convert-an-escaped-string-into-a-literal-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480724/escape-double-quotes-in-string), but it didn't help me.

How can I convert my `string` to `string[]` is this case ?

Comment: Is that a JSON input, or some format of your own? There's plenty of JSON deserialization libraries around.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about this:

```
var output = input.Trim(new[] { '[', ']' }).Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim('\"')).ToArray();
```

Although this might work for your example I recommend using the approach given by @Cuong Le using Json-Deserializer. It is much more robust and also handles nested structures.

Comment: Won't remove the `[` and `]`, won't solve the problem with substrings containing the `"`, like `string input="[\"Mod\\\"ell\"]"`

Comment: I changed it to 'input.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim('\"')).ToArray<string>();' but I get ' [0]: "[\"Modell"
    [1]: "Jan."
    [2]: "Feb."
    [3]: "Mrz."
    [4]: "Apr."
    [5]: "Mai"
    [6]: "Jun."
    [7]: "Jul."
    [8]: "Aug."
    [9]: "Sep."
    [10]: "Okt."
    [11]: "Nov."
    [12]: "Dez.\"]"' actually "Dez" and "Modell" have a backslash too much..

Answer (score 8):

Your input has json format as array of string, so you can simply use the *very popular* library [`Newtonsoft.Json`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) on nuget, and then deserialize back to array of string in C#:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(input);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not very nice, but works:

```
string[] output = input.Replace("[", "").Replace("\"", "").Replace("]", "").Split(',').ToArray<string>();
```

Comment: "works" - for this specific example. The input is JSON, and for that you simply use a JSON parsing library. The input may contain commas, quotes and nested arrays as well.

Comment: @CodeCaster The input *looks* like JSON, and may be JSON. But unless it's JSON by contract, that assumption is kind of dangerous. I've dealt with so many "XML-like" formats in the past that I really don't like those kinds of assumptions anymore :D It's just way too likely that the input is produced by mindlessly slapping strings together, just like it used to be done with INI, CSV, XML or even HTTP before.

Comment: @Luaan questions as vague as this should not be answered in the first place. Assuming it is _not_ JSON and writing your own parser is at least as dangerous.