# c# Replace backslash in json string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json string like this: {\"active\": true} and I want replace for this {"active": true}. How can I do that in c#?

I tried `jsonString.Replace("\\", "");`
 `jsonString.Replace(@"\", "");`
 `jsonString.Replace(@"\"", "");`

nothing worked

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the original string contains slashes `\ ` before each quote `"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I expand a string that contains C# literal expressions at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298075/can-i-expand-a-string-that-contains-c-sharp-literal-expressions-at-runtime)

Comment: How do you know that you have that backslash as part of the string? Are you looking at the string variable containing the json **using the debugger**? If so then the backslash characters are just the debugger being "helpful" in terms of trying to show you how you would declare a constant in C# to produce that string, but the backslash characters aren't really part of the string.

Comment: I am also assuming that you assigned the *result* of calling `Replace` to a string variable? `.Replace` won't *change* the string you call it on, it will return a new string with the changes. ie. this will work: `jsonString = jsonString.Replace(...);`, this will not: `jsonString.Replace(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you want replace `\"` to `"` you can use `Replace.("\\\"", "\"")`.

You need escape special characters like `\` and `"`. So `\` becomes `\\`, `"` becomes `\"`, and `\"` becomes `\\\"`.

Answer (score 0):

Check Regex.Unescape(string) method. This method returns a new string without escape character.

Comment: String strJson= "{\"active\": true}" ;
   string s=   Regex.Unescape(strJson);

Comment: `Unescape` removes backslash only for regexp special characters like `*`, `+` and so no. Not for quote `"`.