# Transforming a string into a escaped char

Tags: c#

The goal is to have a string input (coming from the frontend), and this string should be transformed to act as a escaped char in the backend.

In the following example I want the user to write "\" + "t", and the backend should interpret it as "\t" (= tab char):

```
    var inputStr = @"\t"; // The input is a string written by a user: "\t" (backslash char + t char == @"\t" != "\t")
    var outputStr = SomeOperation(inputStr); // ???
    Console.WriteLine("A" + outputStr + "B <= should be tab separated");
```

I have tried:

```
var outputStr = inputStr.Replace("\", "");
```

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the string `\t` into a tab character?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: `var outputStr = inputStr.Replace(@"\", "\\");`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the post to try to clarify what I am trying to achieve: `The goal is to have a string input (coming from the frontend) that should act as a escaped char in the backend. In the following example I want the user to write "\" + "t", and the backend should interpret it as "\t" (= tab char).`

Comment: Not possible out of the box afaik. You would have to build our own function. This might help to get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I expand a string that contains C# literal expressions at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298075/can-i-expand-a-string-that-contains-c-sharp-literal-expressions-at-runtime)

Comment: @Oram It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: as @marc-gravell pointed out, only inputStr.Replace(@"\t","\t") will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found an easy way to do it:

```
Regex.Unescape(inputStr);
```

See the [documentation of the `Regex.Unescape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape) function for more details.

Example:

```
var ouptutStr = Regex.Unescape("\\t"); 
// ✓ Result: outputStr == "\t"
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something that is built in. Ultimately, `"\t"` == (a string of length 1 containing a tab character) is implemented by the C# compiler, not the runtime. There isn't a pre-existing implementation of this in the runtime, in part because each language (VB.NET, C#, F#, etc) can have their own rules.

You would need to write your own implementation with your own definitions of escape characters. Fortunately, it is mostly an exercise in `.Replace(...)`. There *are* some edge cases to think about - in particular for ordering - though; for example, if `\\` becomes `\` and `\n` becomes newline; does `\\n` become `\n`? or does it become `\(newline)`? done naively, it *can* end up as just (newline) - i.e. `foo.Replace(@"\\",@"\").Replace(@"\n","\n")`

Comment: I see. I was wondering: if we respect the hypothesis "just one single output char is expected", could there be way to convert the input string into a escaped char? Example: "," becomes "," (no change), "\\n" becomes "\n", and maybe even "\\u1F642" (= thumbs up unicode char) becomes "\u1F642". The range of assumptions that are needed seems much more limited in this specific case.

Comment: @XavierPeña ultimately, it is your system - so : if that hypothesis/assumption fits your needs: great, do that

Comment: I was asking for help about _if_ this could be done (with the restrictive hypothesis) and _how_ it could be done. One of the comments is showing a hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal, so I am guessing it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    Debug.Assert(ReplaceChar("hello\tworld", @"\t") == "helloworld"); // passed
}

string ReplaceChar(string str, string userInput)
{
    switch (userInput)
    {
        case @"\t":
            return str.Replace("\t","");
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`var outputStr = Char.Parse("\t").ToString();`
gives

> A       B <= should be tab separated

It isn't seen here but in console it looks properly.

Comment: It shows an exception: `String must be exactly one character long.`. In your code, you are using "\t" instead of "\\t" (or @"\t"), which is the tab character in itself.

Comment: Yes, but `"\t"` argument gives me the real tab symbol in console.