# Parse chars in escape sequence form

Tags: c#

I'm implementing a compiler, and I need to convert from an escape character literal written in source code file to an actual value.

For example I might have a line of source code `char = '\\'`. I then parse that and get given the string `"'\\'"`, which I need to turn into the actual char `'\\'`.

`char.Parse` and `char.TryParse` both fail when parsing a char in escape sequence form. For example:

```cs
char.Parse(@"\\");
```

Will throw "String must be exactly one character long."

Is there any way to parse everything on [this list](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/) as a char (ignoring those that are to big to fit in a UTF16 char).

Comment: How are you getting this "*escape sequence form*" ? who is supplying it, or are you getting confused at what you are seeing in the visual studio editor ?

Comment: The string shown in the sample is 2 characters long (2 back slashes) - could you please clarify what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @TheGeneral this is coming in from a parser

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm implementing a compiler, and I need to convert from an escape character literal in the form of eg "//" to an actual value.

Comment: It sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298075/can-i-expand-a-string-that-contains-c-sharp-literal-expressions-at-runtime is your actual question... but it is *very* hard to get to from sample in your post...

Comment: Sorry @AlexeiLevenkov. I have my head in the context, so it feels very obvious to me, but I can see how it could seem very confusing to someone outside the context. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5):

the `@` makes it a verbatim string literal. drop that and `\` will be treated as the escape char for the next `\`.

```
@"\\".Length // 2
"\\".Length // 1
```

Comment: This is coming in from a string - that was just by way of example

Comment: in that case @YairHalberstadt please provide a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: That is a minimal reproducible example. It's just that since I'm reading a string from a file, I can't drop the @.

Comment: @YairHalberstadt that makes no sense. verbatim string literals are a compile time thing.

Comment: @DanielA.White I think the actual question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298075/can-i-expand-a-string-that-contains-c-sharp-literal-expressions-at-runtime

Comment: I have a source code file containing something like '\\'. The parser gives me "'\\'". I need to say "thats equavalent to the char '\\'.