# Convert escape sequences from user input into their real representation

Tags: c, escaping, lolcode

I'm trying to write an interpreter for LOLCODE that reads escaped strings from a file in the form:

```
VISIBLE "HAI \" WORLD!"
```

For which I wish to show an output of:

```
HAI " WORLD!
```

I have tried to dynamically generate a format string for printf in order to do this, but it seems that the escaping is done at the stage of declaration of a string literal.

In essence, what I am looking for is exactly the opposite of this question:
[Convert characters in a c string to their escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535023/convert-characters-in-a-c-string-to-their-escape-sequences)

Is there any way to go about this?

Comment: `if(str[i] == '\\')
{
    switch(str[++i])
    {
        case 'a':   printf("\a");
                    break;

        ...
    }
}`

Well, this seems to be the easiest way of going about doing things, but probably doesn't deal with all the escape characters. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pretty standard scanning exercise.  Depending on how close you intend to be to the LOLCODE specification (which I can't seem to reach right now, so this is from memory), you've got a few ways to go.

## Write a lexer by hand

It's not as hard as it sounds.  You just want to analyze your input one character at a time, while maintaining a bit of context information.  In your case, the important context consists of two flags:

- one to remember you're currently lexing a string.  It'll be set when reading `"` and cleared when reading `"`.
- one to remember the previous character was an escape.  It'll be set when reading `\` and cleared when reading the character after that, no matter what it is.

Then the general algorithm looks like: (pseudocode)

```
loop on: c ← read next character
  if not inString 
    if c is '"' then clear buf; set inString
    else [out of scope here]
  if inEscape then append c to buf; clear inEscape
  if c is '"' then return buf as result; clear inString
  if c is '\' then set inEscape
  else append c to buf
```

You might want to refine the `inEscape` case should you want to implement `\r`, `\n` and the like.

## Use a lexer generator

The traditional tools here are [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) and [flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser).

## Get inspiration

You're not the first one to write a LOLCODE interpreter.  There's nothing wrong with peeking at how the others did it.  For example, here's [the string parsing code from lci](https://github.com/justinmeza/lci/blob/610f897733e18cf7f59414c2f213f1c3b410f612/lexer.c#L294).