# C# equivalent to toSource() of javascript

Tags: c#, .net, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I convert a C# string value to an escaped string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal)

How I can show the contents of a string in 'pure mode',including `\r`,`\n`,`\t` etc..
equivalent to `.toSource()` method of javascript

For example:

**JavaScript:**

```
var str = "foo\nbaa\ttest"; 
console.log(str.toSource());
```

Output:

```
(new String("foo\nbaa\ttest"))
```

it is possible do this in C#?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

See the answer to [Can I convert a C# string value to an escaped string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal) . He wrote this extension method that does exactly what you're wanting:

```
static string ToLiteral(string input)
{
    var writer = new StringWriter();
    CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(input), writer, null);
    return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Escape("foo\nbaa\ttest")
```

Comment: @Ahmad I saw, but you had a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the general problem - reconstructing some source code - there is no language option on C# that would let you do it automagically.

However (this is theory on my part) you should be able to use expressions to get to the IL equivalent (using the [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx) or [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) libraries perhaps). You could I suspect then use the libraries from the [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) project to reconstruct the C#.