# Representing a Char with equivalent string

Tags: c#, string, formatting, char

I have the following class as a `DataSource` for a ListBox:

```
class SeparatorChars
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Text to describe character
    /// </summary>
    public string Text { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Char value of the character
    /// </summary>
    public char Value { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represent object as string
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>String representing object</returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text + " '" + Value + "'";
    }
}
```

The problem is, this by default will use the `Value` just as a regular character added to a string, for example if I define this class for `Tab` like this:

```
var TabSeparator = new SeparatorChars {Text = "Tab", Value = '\t'}
```

The string representation will be:

```
Tab '     '
```

But I need it to be

```
Tab '\t'
```

How to do this?!

Comment: `\t` is the tab character. Looks like you are getting a tab between the `''`. Looks right to me. Am I missing something? Why do you want to output the string `\t`?

Comment: Thing is, I want it in ToString method to show \t instead of a normal tab.

Comment: Then don't use a tab character but the string `\t`.

Comment: No I need to use the real character for Value property, since I am going to pass it to another class. If I do for example `var comma = new SeparatorChars {Text = "Comma", Value = ','}` This will be fine.

Comment: @Oliver - That's _two_ characters.

Comment: Take a look at this question. The accepted answer may be able to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Admittedly ripped mostly from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal) and untested.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return ToLiteral(Text + " '" + Value + "'");
}

private string ToLiteral(string input)
{
    var writer = new StringWriter();
    CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(input), writer, null);
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hmmm thanks, this works somehow...the representation for tab is now `"Tab \'\t\"'` Seems like everyting is escaped :P

Comment: @Sean87: What if you use it like this: `return ToLiteral(Value.ToString());`? (I'd test it myself, but I'm about to leave for work and on a linux box).

Comment: I think it will be the same thing, since it is going to translted to string automaticly...that will be again `'  TAAAAAB!   '` instead of '\t'

Comment: OK ok ...I had to use `return Text + " -> " + ToLiteral(Value.ToString()).Replace("\"", "");` :P Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a blog post with some sample code: [Mark Gu: Escape Sequences in C#](http://markyourfootsteps.wordpress.com/2010/10/19/escape-sequences-in-csharp/)

Comment: Looks similar to the approach I would take... A simple lookup table.