# How to add new row to database with OleDb on a ASP.Net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, arrays, ms-access

The problem:

I have a webpage with 18 text box fields that I need to insert into a row. The column names are kept inside a Label array called `labelArray`. The text fields that the user enters data in will be in a Textbox array called `textArray.Text`.

I want to know how I can pass all 18 of my text fields in `textArray` to my Data Access Layer where I make my insert these fields into the database. My problem right now is that I cannot pass and array over to a class file. Is it possible to covert to string and pass over the insert string to my Data Access Layer?

The problem in more depth:

There is two columns with data that are set to Date/Time in my MS access database. How can I pass through a Date Time object to my access table? Is it ok if it's a formated string?

If you need to see some code I have, I'm ready to post them and will be on StackOverflow for the next few hours.

Comment: Why can't you pass in the values? Does the method signature not support all those values? If that is the case, what does the method signature look like, and how do you expect to use those parameters to insert the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will convert a `Textbox[]` into an equivalent string representation:

```
var str = String.Join("\",\"", TextArray.Select(tb => tb.Text));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) {
    str = "\"" + str + "\"";
}
str = "[" + str + "]";
```

Keep in mind that double-quotation marks will not be escaped. Solutions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal) and [here](http://www.hariscusto.com/programming/escape-string-in-c/).