# Improper Neutralization of CRLF Sequences in HTTP Headers ('HTTP Response Splitting')

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, html, c#-3.0, veracode

After R&D i didn't solution to this.Please find below piece of code and help me with this veracode flaw.

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition"," attachment; filename = " + Session["user_id"] + "_makler.pdf");
```

**DESCRIPTION** - A function call contains an HTTP response splitting flaw. Writing unsanitized user-supplied input into an HTTP header
allows an attacker to manipulate the HTTP response rendered by the browser, leading to cache poisoning and crosssite
scripting attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the user input and this will be fixed.

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition"," attachment; filename = " + Server.UrlEncode(Session["user_id"]) + "_makler.pdf");
```

Comment: This worked for me and passed the Veracode scan.  I used HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filename).  As with most of Veracode's scan details, it doesn't lead you to fix the answer but to find it in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple issue
just add

```
Session["user_id"].ToString().Replace("\n",String.Empty).Replace("\r",String.Empty)
```