# Preventing CRLF vulnerability on request header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-middleware, crlf-vulnerability

i'm trying to fix the CRLF vulnerability on my application logger im currently logging my http request Path is there a way to validate this one? to remove any CR LF injection on my request Path im currently using c# as my programming language

this is my core code when logging error

```
 _logger.LogInformation(e, "InactiveTenantException caught during api request {RequestPath} {Tenant} {User}", context.Request.Path, currentUser?.Tenant, currentUser?.LoginEmail);
```

note. currently using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging as my logging tool

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, all you need to do is sanitize the URL string you received.  See here for an example

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23033913/1427406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using [`PathString`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/12f89f66a687bdb1c1b683b0d7abd2732c05eb1a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/PathString.cs) that is returned by [`HttpContext.Request.Path`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/12f89f66a687bdb1c1b683b0d7abd2732c05eb1a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Internal/DefaultHttpRequest.cs#L61) you are getting an escaped string:

> the path string escaped in a way which is correct for combining into the URI representation

Thus, there shouldn't be CRLF vulnerability in your code.

If you will make a request like `/foo%5Cnbar` wich is encoded `/foo\nbar` then you will get `/foo%5Cnbar` istead of two lines in your log file.