# Improper Neutralization of CRLF Sequences ('CRLF Injection') (CWE ID 93)

Tags: java, veracode, crlf-vulnerability

In Veracode report I am getting Error CWE 93 in some of the java files. In Instance of static scan some code is

1. `MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
   msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(msmtpfrom));`

2.`msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);`

How do i resolve ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think this question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55705862/improper-neutralization-of-crlf-sequences-in-http-headers

Comment: This resource might help you understand the kind of attack better: https://www.veracode.com/security/crlf-injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the CRLF occurrences in your string variables like msmtpfrom, address with empty string (""). Have a look at similar question that has relevant answers: [How to fix "Improper Neutralization of CRLF Sequences in HTTP Headers ('HTTP Response Splitting')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993290/how-to-fix-improper-neutralization-of-crlf-sequences-in-http-headers-http-res)

Comment: What is the fix for this issue?