# Improper Neutralization of CRLF Sequences in HTTP Headers

Tags: java, xss, veracode

I ran Veracode scan on my project and it gave me CWE ID 113 issue under HTTP response splitting. I tried to resolve the issue with there recommendations but it did not work. e.g.

```
try
    {
        String selNhid = req.getParameter("selNhid");
        String redirectURL = "/nhwhoods?action=membersNH&selNhid="+selNhid;
         res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + redirectURL);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

above code is from one of the file. And report showing error at line

```
res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + redirectURL);
```

Any suggestions, how to resolve the issue ?

Comment: what was it that you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed using ESAPI 2.1.0.1 library with:

```
import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI;

ESAPI.httpUtilities().setHeader(response, param, value);
ESAPI.httpUtilities().addCookie(response, cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

how about just removing CRLF sequences from redirectURL parameter, like the error message suggests?

A simple `.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+", "")` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing URL encoding for the selNhid.

```
String redirectURL = "/nhwhoods?action=membersNH&selNhid="
        + URLEncoder.encode(selNhid, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

The above assumes you are working with UTF-8. Now nasty content will be disarmed as %XX bytes.