# Fastest way to escape characters in a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, performance, escaping

I'd like to find the fastest way to replace all reserved characters in a string with their escaped version.

There are two naive ways that come to my mind spontaneously (note that the set of reserved characters is just an example):

A: Using a lookup dictionary and [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29)

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _someEscapeTokens = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"\t", @"\t"},
    {"\n", @"\n"},
    {"\r", @"\r"}
};

public string GetEscapedStringByNaiveLookUp(string s)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> escapeToken in _someEscapeTokens.Where(kvp => s.Contains(kvp.Key)))
    {
        s = s.Replace(escapeToken.Key, escapeToken.Value);
    }
    return s;
}
```

B: Traversing each character in the string

```
public string GetEscapedStringByTraversingCharArray(string s)
{
    char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (chars[i])
        {
            case '\t':
                sb.Append(@"\t"); break;
            case '\n':
                sb.Append(@"\n"); break;
            case '\r':
                sb.Append(@"\r"); break;
            default:
                sb.Append(chars[i]); break;
         }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

As I've already tested, Version B outperforms the first one easily.

**Note:** I already considered [Regex.Escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but since the character set doesn't match mine, it doesn't fit.

However, are there other ways you would approach this problem (with performance in mind)?

#### More testing

See below for the code.

Testing was done on *two different systems* targeting the *.NET Framework 4.0*. Anyway, the results are pretty much the same:

```
Char Array (short string) average time: 38600 ns
Foreach (short string) average time: 26680 ns
Char Array (long string) average time: 48,1 ms
Foreach (long string) average time: 64,2 ms
Char Array (escaping only) average time: 13,6 ms
Foreach (escaping only) average time: 17,3 ms
```

Which leads me to the conclusion that the `foreach` version seems to be slightly faster for short strings, but it somehow "falls of" for longer strings. However, we're talking about really small differences here.

Testing code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //around 700 characters
    string shortString = new StackTrace().ToString();
    string longString;
    string pureEscape;
    //loading from a file with 1000000 words http://loremipsum.de/
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\users\ekrueger\desktop\LoremIpsum.txt"))
    {
        longString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    //text file containing only escapable characters (length ~1000000)
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\users\ekrueger\desktop\PureEscape.txt"))
    {
        pureEscape = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    List<double> timesCharArrayShortString = new List<double>();
    List<double> timesForeachShortString = new List<double>();
    List<long> timesCharArrayLongString = new List<long>();
    List<long> timesForeachLongString = new List<long>();
    List<long> timesCharArrayPureEscape = new List<long>();
    List<long> timesForeachPureEscape = new List<long>();
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        GetEscapedStringByTraversingCharArray(shortString);
        sw.Stop();
        timesCharArrayShortString.Add(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000000);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        GetEscapedStringForeach(shortString);
        sw.Stop();
        timesForeachShortString.Add(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds * 1000000);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        GetEscapedStringByTraversingCharArray(longString);
        sw.Stop();
        timesCharArrayLongString.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        GetEscapedStringForeach(longString);
        sw.Stop();
        timesForeachLongString.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        GetEscapedStringByTraversingCharArray(pureEscape);
        sw.Stop();
        timesCharArrayPureEscape.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        GetEscapedStringForeach(pureEscape);
        sw.Stop();
        timesForeachPureEscape.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Char Array (short string) average time: {0} ns", timesCharArrayShortString.Average());
    Console.WriteLine("Foreach (short string) average time: {0} ns", timesForeachShortString.Average());
    Console.WriteLine("Char Array (long string) average time: {0} ms", timesCharArrayLongString.Average());
    Console.WriteLine("Foreach (long string) average time: {0} ms", timesForeachLongString.Average());
    Console.WriteLine("Char Array (escaping only) average time: {0} ms", timesCharArrayPureEscape.Average());
    Console.WriteLine("Foreach (escaping only) average time: {0} ms", timesForeachPureEscape.Average());

    Console.Read();
}

private static string GetEscapedStringByTraversingCharArray(string s)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return s;

    char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (chars[i])
        {
            case '\t':
                sb.Append(@"\t"); break;
            case '\n':
                sb.Append(@"\n"); break;
            case '\r':
                sb.Append(@"\r"); break;
            case '\f':
                sb.Append(@"\f"); break;
            default:
                sb.Append(chars[i]); break;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

public static string GetEscapedStringForeach(string s)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return s;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
    foreach (Char ch in s)
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
            case '\t':
                sb.Append(@"\t"); break;
            case '\n':
                sb.Append(@"\n"); break;
            case '\r':
                sb.Append(@"\r"); break;
            default:
                sb.Append(ch); break;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal?rq=1? You can then run performance comparisons and see which implementation is the fastest. And if you could share the results we would all be thankful...

Comment: We spent a lot of time testing a similar problem. We didn't get any faster than the StringBuilder method which was pretty much identical to yours.

Comment: Don't forget that a string is already addressable by index, so ToCharArray is redundant and chums memory for no gain.

Comment: Yes, so change the for loop to: `foreach (char ch in s)` and then do `switch (ch)`

Comment: @qqbenq I didn't tried this solution because of Timwi's comment in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/324812/1409903.

Comment: As side comment, don't forget to escape escape (`'\'` -> `@"\\"`), otherwise you will have decoding problem if `t`, `n` or `r` will follow normal escape char.

Comment: @Sinatr Good point although this character set was just to showcase my problem.

Comment: @spender Whilst testing I also looked at this and there seems to be a slight advantage using char[] instead of string indexer (at least on my setup).

Comment: @EKrueger lesur has an answer there which fixes that problem (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14719643/1552016)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no need to convert `string` into `Char[]`, so the solution can be slightly improved:

```
public string GetEscapedStringByTraversingCharArray(string s) {
  // do not forget about null...
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    return s;

  // we can be sure, that it requires at least s.Length symbols, let's allocate then
  // in case we want to trade memory for speed we can even put
  //   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 * s.Length);
  // for the worst case when all symbols should be escaped
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);

  foreach(Char ch in s) {
    switch (ch) {
      case '\t':
        sb.Append(@"\t"); 

        break;
      case '\n':
        sb.Append(@"\n"); 

        break;
      case '\r':
        sb.Append(@"\r"); 

        break;
      default:
        sb.Append(ch); 

        break;
    }
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I've added some test results to my answer. However i liked pointing out the String.IsNullOrEmpty and initialization of the StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense that the first option is slower since you're creating a lot of string objects with:

```
s = s.Replace(escapeToken.Key, escapeToken.Value);
```

In the second method, there's no need to create a char[] because string has an indexer too.
Perhaps the only thing you can do to improve performance is initialize the StringBuilder with a capacity, so it doesn't need to resize.
You can still use the Dictionary in the second method.