# Encode\escape string for .NET

Tags: .net, encoding, character-encoding, escaping

I have a string of assorted white-space:  e.g.

```
"\t\r "
```

I need to display it in an error message, but just showing white-space isn't helpful.

Is there a method to encode the string for displaying?

Comment: Doesn't normal escaping, ie. @"\t\r" work or did I miss something again?

Comment: @Sami: I think the issue is he wants to convert the string "\t\r" to the string "\\t\\r" programatically, or e.g. "Hello\tWorld" to "Hello\\tWorld"

Comment: @Sami Exactly as Eric says.  It's to be printed in the error message.

Comment: Ok. I don't understand why you want to display double backslashes, but I don't think I have to either :)

Comment: @Sami: Because the backslash escapes a backslash.  The following are equivalent: @"\t\r" and "\\t\\r".

Comment: Exactly. I would have done something like string.Format (@"Hello{0}world", whitespaces).

Comment: ..and now it just hit me that you prolly don't get the whitespace chars so neatly packed as a string. So never mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specifically need the C# escaping convention, you can URL encode the string.  That will provide a visible encoding for non-printable and whitespace characters.  For a table comparing the output of various encoding options, see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11236038/141172

If you do need the C# escaping convention, you could do something as simple as

```
string output = original.Replace("\t", "\\t").Replace("\r", "\\r); // etc
```

If this is for occasionally outputting an error message, the inefficiency of creating a new string for each call to .Replace will not matter.  If it does matter, you could create a method / an extension method that loops through each character in the input string and outputs either the original character, or an escaped version, as appropriate (e.g. using StringBuilder to build up the output string).

**UPDATE**

Here's an extension method that does exactly what you want:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/324812/141172

Comment: Performance isn't a problem yet, it's for the regression suite and only for a few cases in that.  `Replace()` will do the trick I think.  The OCD in me hoped there would be a more _elegant_ method.

Comment: Well write an extension method once, and then you have an elegant method :-)  But I'm not aware of anything in the framework that does what you need.  Leave the question open for a bit; perhaps there is something I'm not aware of.

Comment: Hey... I just found an extension method on StackOverflow that does exactly what you want.  I'll close this question as a duplicate.  Check out the accepted answer there.

Comment: Fair do's, that's a good spot. Cheers.