# How to convert string or character to 'escaped representation'?

Tags: c#

Given this sample code:

```
var s = "abc\r\ndef";
foreach (var c in s)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Current char: {c}");
}
```

Of course, the `'\r'` and `'\n'` characters, are written as whitespace and an actual newline, respectively. What I want to achieve is to write `'\r'`, `'\n'` instead.

What's the easiest way to convert a character to it's (C#) 'escaped representation'? Should I look at Roslyn for this, or is there a simple conversion function available?

Comment: try `var s = @"abc\r\ndef";` intead.

Comment: You want `\r` and `\n` to be treated as a single character?

Comment: `s = s.Replace(@"\r\n", "\xd\xa")` ?

Comment: Nice, despite searching I didn't find the other question. Thanks @YuvalItzchakov.

Comment: @ZoharPeled in reality the string comes from a file, sorry I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question, you can see it here:
[Can I convert a C# string value to an escaped string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal)

```
private static string ToLiteral(string input)
{
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
        {
            provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(input), writer, null);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```