# How to output the string with control character escape sequences

Tags: .net, string, control-characters

How to output the string with character escape sequences (e.g. in the Console)?

The goal is to display the "hidden" control characters from a string.

Example:
For the string
"first line
second line with a   tab... and more line breaks

Next line"

you want to see the output like in the visual studio

[image]

Is in .net something out of the box available for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I convert a C# string value to an escaped string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal)

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggested ToLiteral does not work with a string, which is not declared in code, e.g. loaded from a database or read from a file.