# Console.Writeline escape character from variable

Tags: c#, string

I've got an extension method that converts me `ulong` into a string value with some kind of encryption. I want to output them as they are just by using `Console.WriteLine`, in most scenarios it works but there is a problem with values with escapes characters. For example `"(V\\\|RN"` outputs just `"(V\|RN"`.

```
var result = id.IdToCode();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(id.IdToCode());
```

The method `IdToCode` returns `stringBuilder.ToString()`

I've tried many combinations with putting somewhere `@` to return the string as it is but without any result. Maybe I should override the default behavior of `Console.WriteLine` or the `stringBuilder.ToString()` is the problem here?

Here is a screen of what I mean.

[image: Console output]

And below the code of `IdToCode` method:

```
        public static string IdToCode(this ulong value)
    {
        const string charArray = @"1234890qwertyuiopbnmQWERTYUasdfghjklzxcvIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM!+={}[]|\<>?@#567$%^&*()-_";
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        ulong num = value;
        while (num != 0UL)
        {
            ulong index = num % (ulong)charArray.Length;
            num /= (ulong)charArray.Length;
            stringBuilder.Insert(0, charArray[(int)index].ToString());
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

I've changed the char array into different one but the general method it's the same as above.

Comment: Post the code of `IdToCode`, the problem must be there

Comment: `"(V\|RN" outputs just "(V\|RN".`  - Both looks the same to me.

Comment: Please debug your code and check the value of `IdToCode`

Comment: I don't get which characters are missed.

Comment: Sorry the stack overflow automatically escaped the double \\ char. And I doubt the problem is inside the IdToCode method since it returns me the correct value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I convert a C# string value to an escaped string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal)

Comment: which version of .NET are you using ? var foo = @"foo \\|";
  Console.WriteLine(foo); on 4.5 works fine.

Comment: .NET Core 2.0 I think I need to study the possible duplicate question but gonna to that later.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you need to use the `@` in front of the string literal which actually adds the backslash to the `StringBuilder`.

There is no point in doing `@id.IdToCode()`, because when the `string` is returned, it already contains `(V\|RN`. The tooltip shows `\\` because it shows the escaped eversion - meaning the single backslash.

One thing that is certain is that the problem can't be resolved here, but only inside the `IdToCode` method, where it actually originates.

Compare this (same as your code):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var str = IdToCode();
    Console.WriteLine();
}

public static string IdToCode()
{
    return "(\\VN";
}
```

Hovering over `str` I see `(\\VN` - two backslashes, output is just one backslash - which is correct.

And this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var str = IdToCode();
    Console.WriteLine();
}

public static string IdToCode()
{
    return @"(\\VN";
}
```

Here the tooltip shows `"(\\\\VN"` which is again correct - there are two actual backslashes and console output is the desired `(\\VN`

Comment: "The problem can't be resolved here" . Not true -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal

Comment: Ok, proper wording should probably be "should not be resolved here" :-D . If you are a receiver of a escaped string, how can you tell which backslashes are actual backslashes and which are escapes. If the string is created inside the `IdToCode` method, it should return the correct string itself, otherwise the method is poorly written.

Comment: The thing is the IdToCode method actually returns just one backslash. It is **displayed** as two in the tooltip, but it is there just once.