# C# - Deserializing when whitespace between tags is delimited

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization, string-parsing

I am posting some XML to an API Gateway method in AWS, which has an integration to SNS. An SQS queue is then subscribed to the topic; and I have a C# process which polls the queue intermittently and needs to deserialize the XML.

The trouble is, the whitespace between the XML tags ends up getting encoded along the line somewhere, so tabs become `\t` and new lines become `\r\n`. But these end up as *physical tokens* inside the string.

Example XML which is posted to API Gateway:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProfileInformation>
    <Username>bgs264</Username>
</ProfileInformation>
```

String which is read off the SQS queue:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<ProfileInformation>\n\t<Username>bgs264</Username>\n</ProfileInformation>
```

Note that the attributes in the declaration end up as `\"` and the whitespace posted ends up as `\t`, `\r\n`, etc.

However these aren't "the strings appearing as such in the debugger, but it's actually a tab", they are *actually like this* in the string.

So when I try to deserialize, using

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(message))
   var myObj = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as ProfileInformation);
```

I get:

**InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 15).**

It refers to the first `\` character in the declaration, as in `version=\"1.0\"`

My immediate idea was to simply `string.Replace` `\t` to empty string, etc, but that's unacceptable because it might be valid that the user's username is actually is `bgs\t264` and the replace here would cause an inconsistency. In this example, I presume I would get `bgs\\t264` in the message, so a replace would leave me, erroneously, with `bgs\264` for example.

So I need to fix these `\n\t` characters where they occur between XML tags.

For what it's worth, I also have a lambda written in Go which has no problem with this and simply deserializes the exact same string straight into XML. So it must be possible.

My intial thoughts:

- Can I somehow decode the string before passing it for
  deserialization? I tried this with `HttpUtility.DecodeHtml` but I
  don't think it's actually HTML that I'm trying to decode!
- Is there a different XML library I can use that would work?

Comment: There are questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal) that would help you unescape the string, but I think I'd encourage investigating how and why this is happening and try to prevent it.

Comment: It's possible/likely that your message is being serialised as JSON, so if you can't stop this you could use a JSON library (like Newtonsoft.Json) to reverse the process (e.g. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(message)`).

Comment: @CharlesMager It was a great idea, but I'm afraid, no dice. `JsonReaderException Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 1, position 1`

Comment: @CharlesMager I agree with cutting it off at the source, but unfortunately, my API Gateway is directly integrated with SNS - No lambda or any code I control in the middle. I suppose I could instead integrate it with a lambda which cleanses and reposts to the topic, if required.

Comment: Wrap it in quotes first. See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5lA57Q).

Comment: Do you really have a backslash before the double quote or is the double quote just showing up in the debugger?  XML ignores white spaces.  So I think the error is somebody actually put a backslash into the string which is wrong and is giving the error.  Open string in note pad and make sure you do not have the backslash.

Comment: @CharlesMager Thank you! It works! Feel free to post it as an answer so I can accept, if you like.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for your comment but as I tried to express in the question, it is part of the string and not just the debugger. No worries, I have a solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess, and some googling seems to support the theory, that the message you're seeing has been converted to JSON & the escape sequences are as a consequence of that.

The ideal approach would be to investigate and prevent this from happening. I don't know enough about SNS to advise & you indicate this is a non-starter, so the simplest approach would be to reverse this process once you receive the message.

You can use a JSON library like [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to do this:

```cs
var jsonString = string.Format("\"{0}\"", message);

var xmlString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(jsonString);

using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
{
   var profileInformation = (ProfileInformation) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```