# Convert a C# string value to an escaped string literal with Roslyn

Tags: c#, string, roslyn, literals, converters

There is such method for CodeDom by **@Hallgrim** found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal):

```
private static string ToLiteral(string input)
{
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
        {
            provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(input), writer, null);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Nowadays we need a Roslyn remake for .NET Core. Or should we manually replace symbols?

Comment: Something likes this: `SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(input)).ToFullString();` ?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria, it works. Please post as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `SyntaxNode` (`LiteralExpressionSyntax`) from the input string and than take the string representation of the created node:

```
public static string ToLiteral(this string input)
{
    return SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(input)).ToFullString();
}
```