# Escape a string as though it was for a C# string literal? (eg. "repr" representation)

Tags: c#, string, escaping

There are various methods in C# to escape strings, most deal with XML ([SecurityElement.Escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securityelement.escape?view=netframework-4.8)) or JavaScript ([HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode?view=netframework-4.8)).

**Is there a standard .NET (.NET Standard 2.0) method to escape a string such that, when copied verbatim in a C# double-quoted literal, it will evaluate to original string?**

Here is a sample desired transform of the *string content* from `ff "Hello world!" ^M^M <>'` to `ff \"Hello world!\" \n\n <>'` so that it can be copied verbatim into a valid program:

```
 var x = "ff \"Hello world!\" \n\n <>'";
```

Note that `^M` (new line character) is transformed to the `\n` escape and `<>'` is left alone as angle brackets are irrelevant in context and the string will be double-quoted (escaping of `'` would be OK).

Consider the VS Debugger expression view's rendition of string values for an example of desired output. Sometimes this might be referred to as 'string representation form'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a C# string value to an escaped string literal with Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55514123/convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal-with-roslyn)

Comment: @GSerg Thanks, that's the output I'm looking for. Unfortunately it establishes a CodeDomProvider/Roslyn dependency which is a bit .. heavy.

Comment: Well, I guess the next best thing is to manually implement [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences).

Comment: Hmm. I suppose that "encode for a JSON string" might be sufficiently close. Also doesn't appear readily a thing.

Comment: Create a list of key/value pairs (or some other 2-tuple) that represent what you want to do.  Then walk through the list calling `StringBuilder.Replace` for each pair doing the transformation.  StringBuilder's Replace call is more appropriate than string's here.