# Get an object's ToString() to show up '\0' for a string that's a null character?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio

When one wraps a string into an object and make that object `ToString` return that string, `\0` is never shown:

```
public void Test()
{
    var a = "a";
    var b = "\0";
    var c = new ClassA { Value = a };
    var d = new ClassB { Value = b };
}

public class ClassA
{
    public string Value;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public string Value;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

[image]

How can one get `d` to show up as `b` in the debugger?

Comment: Note that the debugger is formatting it the same way you'd need to write a string literal inside your source code, so it's actually the same question faced by source-code generators.

Comment: e.g. already asked (but without satisfactory answer) here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59294777/103167

Comment: and here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/323640/103167

Comment: `\0` is not a displayable character. Note that `b` is not a null string, but a string with a length of 1 that contains a null character.

Comment: aybe, you may want to [edit] the question to clarify if you need fix for debugger display (which is arguably a bug, probably coming from C/C++ string rendering in debugger) or you actually need to change output of `ToString()` irrespective of debugger behavior. Currently duplicate answers one version and answer provide solution for another...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the output of object's ToString is fine actually, it's passthrough.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield That's right, I've updated the title!

Comment: @BenVoigt The answer below did well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can one get d to show up as b in the debugger?

Simply apply the [`DebuggerDisplayAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute) to the `ClassB`:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Value}")]
public class ClassB
{
    public string Value;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This may "get `d` to show up like `b` in the debugger" but you are not changing the result of `ToString()` as the question asked for, and your answer should at least note that you don't answer the question asked but provide a frame challenge.

Comment: @BenVoigt The result of `ToString()` shouldn't be changed since it is `'\0'` (the correct value). And also the topic is named "Get an object's ToString() to **show up** '\0' for null strings?"

Comment: If OP is looking for fix for VS behavior than this definitely a better approach for debugging compared to changing behavior of `ToString` as suggested in the duplicate.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :)