# How to escape special chars when writing into a text file

Tags: c#

I'm reading this string

```
string input = "Hello, my name is \t Peter \n how are you ? ";
```

I'm printing this in my file:

```
Hello, my name is      Peter
how are you?
```

I want the result to be:

```
Hello, my name is \t Peter \n how are you ?
```

How can I escape special characters like tabs and break lines when writing into a file text ?

Comment: `"..... \\t ...."` or `@".... \t ....."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string input = "Hello, my name is \t Peter \n how are you ? ";
input = input.Replace("\n","\\n");
```

You can do the same for others like \t, ...

[What character escape sequences are available?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/)

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AFkp9j)

Comment: thanks, I will mark it as soon as I try it !

Comment: do you know how to replace \ for \\
I tryed string result = input.Replace(@"\","\\");
but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to treat your string as a literal string by prepending the @ character. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

For example:

```
string s = @"Hello, my name is \t Peter \n how are you ? ";
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Will give you the result you are looking for. However note this only works when you have the actual string text between quote marks and will not work with variables.

Also take a look at this question and its answers: [Can I convert a C# string value to an escaped string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal)

Comment: he says that he is reading it (probably from a file), it is not hard coded