# How to print string exactly as it is read from a file?

Tags: c#, .net

I read this string:

```
"\u0093 Safe area to answer the phone\u0094."
```

But when i want to send or rewrite in files, it appears like this:

```
" Safe area to answer the phone."
```

I need to print the original string.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: There's something (important!) you're not telling us, and we can't guess from the information you've provided.  An [MCVE] is an excellent suggestion.

Comment: `\u0093` is a Unicode "Set Transmit State" character (http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/0093.html), while `\u0094` is a "Cancel" character (http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/0094.html).  They both sound like they date back to the age of teletypes (although a teletype character with 8 (rather than 7) bits surprises me).  I don't expect either is printable.  What do you mean by _"it appears like this"_?

Comment: Depending on what you want one of the two duplicates should solve your problem (whether you want `\t` is output or `\u000a`)… If you want other Unicode ranges to be escaped or not you'll have to adjust code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1615860/477420 to match your exact requirements.

Comment: But this still begs the question where exactly the OP is seeing "\u0093".  If he's just reading from a text file, and writing back exactly what he read to another text file, there should be no problem.

Answer (score -1):

The \u0093 is just how the C# language represents unprintable characters. It's called "escaping". So what's being printed is actually what's in the file. A more popular example is that a newline shows up as '\n'. 
See [Can I convert a C# string value to an escaped string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal)  for a code snippet on how to do what the C# language is doing and print the escape characters.