# I want to show weird code/character on textbox winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have no idea how to show weird character code.
example `\n`, `\u0003`. I want to show it `"\n"` or `"\u0003"` on textbox, i.e. I don't want to show the *symbol itself* but *its code*.

any idea?

thank you so much

Comment: Those aren't "weird" characters, they are escape sequences for characters  in the 7-bit US-ASCII range. The first one is just a newline. The second one is the *non*-printable `End of Text` character. Just include those escape sequences in your strings, but don't expect to see anything - they are *non*printable

Comment: By default, text boxes have only a single line and newlines don't affect how the contents look. If you want to display the text in multiple lines, you'll have to set the `Multiline` property to `true`

Comment: The FAQ article [What character escape sequences are available?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available/) shows the available escape sequences for C#

Comment: If you want to *show* `\n`, `textBox1.Text = "\\n";`, if you want to *print* the corresponding Unicode char, remove one slash (e.g., `textBox1.Text = "\u277D";`). Characters with *special* meaning, as `\n` (not `"\u0010"`), will be *treated* accordingly.

Comment: [Convert a C# string value to an escaped string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/323640/3110834).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *encode* the string, i.e. to represent *control characters* with their codes (for instance for some kind of *logging*, *debugging* etc.)

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  private static string Encode(string value) {
    if (null == value)
      return null;

    return string.Concat(value
      .Select(c => char.IsControl(c) 
         ? $"\\u{((int) c):x4}" // control symbol - as a code
         : c.ToString()));      // non-control    - as it is
  }
```

Then

```
  myTextBox.Text = Encode("abc\ndef\r\t566");
```

And you'll have

```
  abc\u000adef\u000d\u0009566
```