# Programmatically escaping a character

Tags: c#, .net, escaping

Is there a standard library method in .Net that will programmatically escape a character? That is, take as input e.g. `'\n'` (the newline character) and return a string containing two characters, the first of which is a backslash and the second of which is a lowercase N? (Regex.Escape seems to do the reverse.)

Comment: Are you sure Regex.Escape isn't what you want? I'm seeing `Regex.Escape("\n")` produce `"\\n"`(a 2 character string).

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal  - it works on a string, but shouldn't be a problem to convert to using a char.

Comment: @JoeSewell Ah, you are quite correct, if you convert the input character to a string first, then it does the job. Thanks!