# Escaped string literals for using in SSH cmd password field

Tags: c#, string, ssh, escaping

I'm working C#, and trying to build up an SSH cmd for mounting a remote drive for archiving.

Building off of this question/answers: [Can I convert a C# string value to an escaped string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal)

I'm using this bit of code to escape any special characters:

```
       // Used to escape any non-standard characters that might be found in the remote archive password
    private static string ToLiteral(string input)
    {

        StringBuilder literal = new StringBuilder(input.Length + 2);            
        literal.Append("\"");
        foreach (var c in input)
        {                
            switch (c)
            {
                case '\'': literal.Append(@"\'"); break;
                case '\"': literal.Append("\\\""); break;
                case ',': literal.Append(@"\,"); break;
                case '\\': literal.Append(@"\\"); break;
                case '\0': literal.Append(@"\0"); break;
                case '\a': literal.Append(@"\a"); break;
                case '\b': literal.Append(@"\b"); break;
                case '\f': literal.Append(@"\f"); break;
                case '\n': literal.Append(@"\n"); break;
                case '\r': literal.Append(@"\r"); break;
                case '\t': literal.Append(@"\t"); break;
                case '\v': literal.Append(@"\v"); break;
                case '$': literal.Append(@"\$"); break;     // Need to have a special case for $....otherwise it breaks the SSH command string
                default:
                    // ASCII printable character
                    if (c >= 0x20 && c <= 0x7e)
                    {
                        literal.Append(c);
                        // As UTF16 escaped character
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        literal.Append(@"\u");
                        literal.Append(((int)c).ToString("x4"));
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        literal.Append("\"");
        return literal.ToString();
    }
}
```

All that is working great, except if there is a " (double quote) or a , (comma) character in the password.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get around this, besides telling the users not to put a " or a , in the password?

ETA:  The code that is putting together the SSH command is here:

```
> pwd = $"echo {sshHost.password} | ";
> cmd = $"sudo -S mount -t cifs {remoteshare} {localshareRoute} -o username={remoteuser},password={escapedDecryptedPasswd}";
> if (mgr.RunCommand(pwd+cmd) == false) return ReturnException(exceptionTitle, mgr.Error);
```

Where the escapedDecryptedPasswd is what is coming from the 'ToLiteral' method.

And the error I get is

> System.Exception: [sudo] password for nsdocker: mount error(22):
> Invalid argument

Thanks!

Comment: and exactly what happens in these circumstances? figure out why the comand is failing, then figure out what the output string should look like, then you should be able to fix your code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual code that you're using to invoke ssh. In particular it'd be nice to see what actual command you're invoking and how the password string is part of it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I've edited the question to include the lines where the SSH command is put together, and what the error response is.