# How to escape a variable

Tags: c#, escaping

I am trying to save some variables to a file.
I am doing it like this

file.Write(organisationId + ";" + Name + ";" + organisationsNummer + ";" + statusCode + ";" + remark + ";" + created + ";" + updated + Environment.NewLine);

It will write a new line for each organization. The problem is that one of the organizations has an organisationsNummer value of "997744276\r" It deletes the \r part and moves the rest to a new line.
How can I save the variables as it is "997744276\r".
I tried to do this @organisationsNummer but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I convert a C# string value to an escaped string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal)

Comment: Where did you get this data from? Does "997744276\r" actually mean the number, a backslash and the letter r, or is it a data error from previous imports? Because "\r" is a control character called "carriage return" (from the old days of typewriters) that does exactly what you describe.

Comment: I get it from a WebAPI - it could be a mistake on their part. But I have to deal with it anyway.

Comment: Sounds like you should Trim organisationsNummer

Answer (score 1):

Please do not try to write csv files by hand. You are doomed. This is the first thing that occurs, next thing you know is you have names that include a `;`. And then the next quirk comes around. And the next and the next and the next.

Get a library that writes CSV files for you. [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/) seems nice, but you can pick another if you like. Just don't waste hours upon hours of fixing your own bug ridden csv file writer please.