# Trying to convert hex to string but get lots of characters instead, works in python but not C#

Tags: python, c#, string, escaping

I'm trying to convert a hexadecimal value to a string. It works fine in python, but in C#, it's just a bunch of characters.

Hex: `"293A4D48E43D5D1FBBFC8993DD93949F"`

### Python

```py
>>> bytearray.fromhex('293A4D48E43D5D1FBBFC8993DD93949F');
bytearray(b'):MH\xe4=]\x1f\xbb\xfc\x89\x93\xdd\x93\x94\x9f')
```

### C#

```
public static string HextoString(string InputText)
{
  byte[] bb = Enumerable.Range(0, InputText.Length)
    .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
    .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(InputText.Substring(x, 2), 16))
    .ToArray();
  return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bb);
  // or System.Text.Encoding.UTF7.GetString
  // or System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString
  // or System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString
  // or etc.
}

HextoString('293A4D48E43D5D1FBBFC8993DD93949F');
// "):MH?=]▼????????"
```

Comment: *it works fine for python* - I don't really know what "works fine" means in an attempt to convert binary data to string. What do you really expect to find in the data?

Comment: @jps ´'):MH\xe4=]\x1f\xbb\xfc\x89\x93\xdd\x93\x94\x9f'´

I want to get it out like this so I can change it.

Answer (score 0):

Python and C# decide what to do with unprintable characters in different ways. In the case of Python, it is printing their escape sequences (eg `\xe4`), but in C#, the unprintable characters are printed as question marks. You may want to [convert the string to an escaped string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal) before you print it.

Comment: Will I get such signs with this?


` return System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bb);`

Don't know how to replace this code.

Comment: Not 100% familiar with C# sadly, but you should refer to the answer I linked, which looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Hi my friend you can choose one of these ways :

1. Convert Hex to String in Python:

   print(bytes.fromhex('68656c6c6f').decode('utf-8'))

2.Using codecs.decode:

```
import codecs

my_string = "68656c6c6f"
my_string_bytes = bytes(my_string, encoding='utf-8')

binary_string = codecs.decode(my_string_bytes, "hex")
print(str(binary_string, 'utf-8'))
```

3.Append hex to string

```
def hex_to_string(hex):
    if hex[:2] == '0x':
        hex = hex[2:]
    string_value = bytes.fromhex(hex).decode('utf-8')
    return string_value

hex_value = '0x737472696e67'
string = 'This is just a ' + hex_to_string('737472696e67')

print(string)
```

Good luck (Arman Golbidi)

Comment: This solution is for Python. They wanted one for C#.

Comment: The code already works in python, but I've switched to C# and am trying to get my code to work there.