# (C#) How can I get a string with escape characters without changing the escape characters?

Tags: c#, file, escaping

I want to save a string to a file (without for example making `\n` into an actual new line).

This is my code:

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Truncate)
{
    var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    List<string> keys = texts.Keys.ToList();
    List<string> vals = texts.Values.ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < texts.Count; i++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(keys[i] + ";" + vals[i]);
    }
    sw.Close();
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to convert a dictionary called `texts` into a file.
In the values, I can have `line1\n\tline2`. I need to somehow make, so that the escape characters dont convert into their actual form.

I would appreciate any help...

EDIT:
Tried doing `sw.WriteLine(keys[i].Replace(@"\", "|") + ";" + vals[i].Replace(@"\", "|");`. It won't save as `|n` or `|t`...

EDIT 2:
You can convert the Literal back to its original form using this oversized algorithm (not all escape characters included)

```
private static string ToNormal(string value)
    {
        string output = "";
        bool escapeChar = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
        {
            if (escapeChar)
            {
                switch (value[i].ToString())
                {
                    case "n":
                        output += "\n";
                        break;
                    case "t":
                        output += "\t";
                        break;
                    case "a":
                        output += "\a";
                        break;
                    case @"\":
                        output += "\\";
                        break;
                }
                escapeChar = false;
            }
            else if (value[i] == '\\')
            {
                escapeChar = true;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                output += value[i];
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Is the goal to write csv-files? if so you probably do not really want to escape linebreaks, but rather to encapsulate all the text in a cell. Or just use json instead and let the library handle everything.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323640/can-i-convert-a-c-sharp-string-value-to-an-escaped-string-literal)

Should be able to do this in the `for` loop:

```
sw.WriteLine(keys[i] + ";" + Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SymbolDisplay.FormatLiteral(vals[i], false));
```

You have to install the `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` Nuget package

Comment: If a question is a duplicate, we don't add a new answer, we close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: sorry, I don't have enough reputation to do that lol.

Comment: @frankM_DN Do you have any idea how to convert the literal form back to its original form?

Comment: @RadarDev I haven't tested this rigorously but looks like you can use `Regex.Unescape(vals[1])`